# How do I sharpen tensor flow images?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Is there a way to sharpen a tensorflow image with Python? Any photo I import into my program seems like it has a haze over it and they are not as clear as they are in my default photo viewer.

Is there a function i should add to bring more clarity to my images? Below is my current code.

```
img = cv2.imread('sample_images/book.jpg')
img=cv2.resize(img,(360,480))
cv2.imshow('My Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 4):

By reducing the dimensions of your image, you will be reducing its image quality. There is no way to reduce its dimensions and retain the same image quality.

That being said, you could try out some different interpolation methods and you might be able to find one that you are okay with. When downsizing an image, my favorite is cv2.INTER_AREA:

```
cv2.resize(src=img, dsize=(360,480), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```